# Получить код всего проекта

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Допустим, имеется проект со сложной иерархией.

Можно ли в VISUAL STUDIO получить исходный код всего проекта, не клацая по всем файлам в проекте?

Comment: Куда получить? В одно окно?

Comment: Допустим в одно окно или в файл, откуда потом его можно будет с легкостью добавить в диплом)

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну как вам сказать..дело в том, что Visual Studio разрабатывалась не для того, чтобы "код с легкостью добавить в диплом". А в продакшн-разработке таких потребностей не возникает

Comment: Команда copy может, в том числе, объединять файлы.

Comment: Вы не программируете, а диплом должен содержать программу. Вижу только один выход: нанимаете исполнителя. Вам будет всё равно легко ли ему вставлять исходные свои тексты в ваш диплом.

Comment: @artoodetoo , проект я разработал и исходники у меня есть. Теперь всю иерархию хочу слить в 1 файл

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сделать вот такое:

```
string rootPath = @"path you your root folder";
var header = "***********************************" + Environment.NewLine;

var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var result = files.Select(path => new { Name = Path.GetFileName(path), Contents = File.ReadAllText(path)})
                  .Select(info =>   
                      header
                    + "Filename: " + info.Name + Environment.NewLine
                    + header
                    + info.Contents);


var singleStr = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
Console.WriteLine ( singleStr );
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.txt", singleStr, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Когда-то помогло.
Нашел вот тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546733/how-to-export-all-the-source-code-from-visual-studio-into-a-text-file